# Userspace and Kernel space graphics drivers for the pi 4

Tags: kernel, driver, gpu

I recently bought a raspberry pi 4 to aid in my computer architecture studies.

Also, one of my study projects is to build a kiosk application using buildroot (not raspbien).

I have taken some time to try and understand the GPU of the pi 4.

From my research, the GPU on the raspberry pi 4 is called the videocore vi.

1. From my understanding, the videocore vi is a complete SOC-like unit on its own with a coprocessor and a 3d engine (plus other stuff). is this correct ?
2. It also appears there are 2 kernel drivers responsible for interacting with the videocore vi (VC4 and V3D drivers). What role does each play in controlling the videocore vi?
3. Is the coprocessor the actual unit in the GPU that is responsible for system start up ?

Comment: You bought the wrong device. The Videocore is closed source.

Comment: @milliways Yes, its something I figured out a few days after i started reading about the pi. But i am looking for high level answers. Not hardware specifics. Just need to know how all the software components (vc4 and v3d) fit